# Edit css selectors in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

So we have users who can define their own templates. However. It's turning out that these templates can live on the same page for a short time, which means the css in template 1 that targets `h1` would also affect any `h1`s in template 2.

Now, if I were writing the CSS, it would be trivial to change code like this:

```
h1 {
  font-family: 'Comic Sans';
}
```

to this:

```
#template-1 h1{
  font-family: 'Comic Sans';
}
```

What I'd like to do, however, is read in all of the CSS, and prepend the template ID to each CSS declaration as I've outlined above. Each template has a slug, so we'll wrap the template in a div with the slug as an ID.

Is there a simple way to prefix selectors with an ID in rails, without using a CSS regex? And if so, are there any gotchas I should be aware of when adding said prefix?

EDIT:

SCSS seems like the way to go. So how do I process something stored in the DB as scss?

Comment: if you have sass enabled, why not just wrap it with `#blah { ... }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SCSS:

```
#template-1 {
  h1 {
    font-family: 'Comic Sans';
  }

  ...
}
```

With SASS:

```
#template-1
  h1
    font-family: 'Comic Sans'

  ...
```

Comment: OK, so the follow up question is how would I process the CSS templates as SCSS in Rails? The CSS is modeled in the template like `template.css`. How would I process that as SCSS for output?

Comment: Let me be clearer... `template` is a rails model. Inside of `template` there's a field called `css`. I need to take that field and process it via `scss`. How would I do that?

Answer (score -1):

I think I understand. You want css to be dynamically generated?

You have a model something like?

```
class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :css
end
```

In production, your assets would already be pre-compiled. Sass by default is only included in the assets group by default. This means that they will run on heroku only when you push you project and compile the assets.

You could move sass-rails out of the assets group, but I have no idea how you would make it process data from your db.

I would possibly store the contents in the database as css and embed it on the view template of your page.

Comment: This is not what I was asking. I'm storing the CSS in the DB already. I'm wondering if I'm going to use SCSS to wrap the body of the CSS, how do I process it using SCSS?

Comment: Could you furter explain what you mean by "use scss to wrap the body of css"?